# conda doesn't see the nuitka package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, nuitka, conda-forge

When trying to compile a file, using the command `conda -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py`
I get an error `CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda nuitka'.`

Used `conda config --add channels conda-forge`and `conda config --set channel_priority strict` before installation (`conda install nuitka`)

When I enter `conda search nuitka` - I get a lot of packages starting from the 0.5.x to 0.7.7 version.
But when I use - `conda list nuitka`.  I get nothing

```
conda --version
conda 4.10.3
```

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `python -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py`?

Comment: python -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py>>>python.exe: No module named nuitka

Comment: Try `python -m pip install nuitka`, then the command ForceBru gave.

Comment: python -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py>>

FATAL: Error, scons failed to create the expected file 'nefilestrict'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have never actually isntalled the package

```
 conda search
```

lists all packages that you **could** install that match the given name

```
conda list
```

lists the currently installed packages. So you need to do

```
conda install nuitka
```

Comment: Great, apparently I was inattentive, I started the installation but did not see if it was completed. But now it turns out the following - 'conda search nuitka --channel conda-forge', shows me that I can install nuitka, but "conda instal nukita", says no -'PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels'

Comment: Can you add the output of `conda install -c conda-forge nuitka` to your question through the edit function?

Comment: I restarted the system and did the path again: {conda config --add channels>conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict > conda install nuitka}, conda issued {Found conflicts right now! Looking for incompatible packages}.   And now: 'Looking for incompatible packages'

Comment: After ~ 3 hours, conda brought out an incredible number of conflicts, and details on them (I even find it difficult to say how many lines there are), for example>                            `Package curio conflicts for:
anyio -> curio
jupyter_server -> anyio[version='>=2.0.2,<3'] -> curio`                                                           result was
`Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.`

Comment: Are you trying to do this in an anaconda base environment? I would advise to create seperate environments for different purposes.

Comment: Thank, there is progress now (`conda list nuitka` - finds `nuitka 0.7.7`), but when entering `conda nuitka -standalone -onefilestrict test.py` still `CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda nuitka'`. Installed the environment `conda create -n Proj numpy pandas nuitka`

Comment: Well as the comments to your question have already pointed out, you need to run `python -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py` while inside the environment

Comment: I am already inside the environment  `conda activate Proj`

Comment: But you are not running `python -m ...` but instead `conda nuitka` which is incorrect

Comment: Great, the main issue of the post can be considered resolved. But now I have the following `Error, the Windows SDK must be installed in Visual Studio.` Despite the fact that VS installer shows me what I have the `SDK for .NET Framework 4.8` . But probably according to the rules of the site,  this is another question?

Comment: Yes, would probably be best to post it as a new question